# In Pandas, combine dictionary with a single value for output dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

If I have a number of dictionaries, how could I best combine them into a single pandas DataFrame? I would also like to have an added column, with a given value for each "batch" of dictionaries.

Example inputs:

```
# Declare initial parameters:
bonuscolumn_name = 'Col_A'
desired_pd = pd.DataFrame(columns=['bonuscolumn_name', 'name', 'age'])

# First batch of dictionaries:
bonuscolumn_value1 = 'somevalue'
dict1 = {'name':'Sam', 'age':26}
dict2 = {'name':'Albert', 'age':21}
dict3 = {'name':'Brock', 'age':57}

# Second batch of dictionaries:
bonuscolumn_value1 = 'diffvalue'
dict4 = {'name':'Fred', 'age':14}
dict5 = {'name':'Philbert', 'age':20}
```

Desired Output:

| Col_A | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| somevalue | Sam | 26 |
| somevalue | Tyler | 21 |
| somevalue | Brock | 57 |
| diffvalue | Fred | 14 |
| diffvalue | Philbert | 20 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dataframe for each diciontary an then use:

```
df = pd.concat([dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5, dict6], keys=[dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5, dict6])
```

Then:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# First batch of dictionaries:
bonuscolumn_value1 = 'somevalue'
dict1 = {'name':'Sam', 'age':26}
dict2 = {'name':'Albert', 'age':21}
dict3 = {'name':'Brock', 'age':57}
df1 = pd.DataFrame([dict1, dict2, dict3]).assign(bonuscolumn_name=bonuscolumn_value1)

# Second batch of dictionaries:
bonuscolumn_value1 = 'diffvalue'
dict4 = {'name':'Fred', 'age':14}
dict5 = {'name':'Philbert', 'age':20}
df2 = pd.DataFrame([dict4, dict5]).assign(bonuscolumn_name=bonuscolumn_value1)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Final output:

```
>>> df
       name  age bonuscolumn_name
0       Sam   26        somevalue
1    Albert   21        somevalue
2     Brock   57        somevalue
3      Fred   14        diffvalue
4  Philbert   20        diffvalue
```

Comment: @SwiftestKoala. I don't understand how the accepted answer solves your problem?